# How MySQL DateTime works

Tags: mysql, datetime

I need to manipulate my database. I'm stuck at `datetime` field. For example, it is `08-Apr-2015 21:13:49` and SQL translate it into `1428527629`. How SQL translate the `d-M-Y H:i:s` format?

Comment: What is the datatype of your date column ?

Comment: @abhik-chakraborty it is `bigint(20)` thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1428527629` unix timestamp, stands for seconds since Jan 01 1970. (UTC)

You have several SQL functions to work with dates, such as:  `FROM_UNIXTIME(1428527629)`

Comment: when i type `SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1428527629);` it return to `2015-04-08 21:13:49`. How I change `2015-04-08 21:13:49` into, for example, `2015-05-08 21:13:49` ?

Comment: i found the solution `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-05-08 21:13:49');` thanks a lot ...